# Disable WP Gutenberg prepublish checks globaly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Im creating custom user edit post interface and i need to completely remove gutenberg pos prepublish checks and publish. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the publish sidebar completly with

```js
wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').disablePublishSidebar();
```

Simply enqueue this JS with a dependance to .

```php
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'so69031961', 'gutenberg-editor.js', [ 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-dom-ready' ] );
} );
```

This will have the same effect than unchecking this box :

[image: disable the prepublish checks sidebar]

So yes, your users might still be able to reactivate the checks, but it's better than nothing ;)